# Want to sue my former employer for wage theft; or settle

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, contract-law, new-york-state, employer

I have not been paid wages for April 2019 and was abruptly laid off on May 8. I want to sue the company. They are moving money out of the U.S., telling employees we'll be paid soon, and seemingly preparing for bankruptcy. A source tells me the company is prepared for former employees trying to file a lawsuit.

My other friend, not giving formal legal advice, says it sounds like an open and shut case, but none of the former employees have the resources at present to sue the company for wages. He says the company is committing wage theft and likely is guilty of "unfair preference" if all this is indeed happening.

Are there any legal firms that would take on this type of case? They're moving money to other countries and employees there have been paid.

Time is a bit of the essence. Sounds like they're going to declare bankruptcy on May 15. They're trying to get us to sign general release documents but I'm holding out so far.

Comment: Your state should have an office, likely under the State Attorney General, or perhaps Labor and Industry, that handles problems such as Wage Theft.   Look into the specifics of your state government.

Comment: If they move their assets out of the country, then why would they care if you sue them or not.  Could even the US Supreme Court give you justice?

Comment: I was going to tell you to contact the Dept of Labor for NY, but their claim form for unpaid wages doesn't include managerial, administrative, nor professional employees (AKA exempt employees).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can sue for wage theft, and assuming the facts are as in the question, should have a good case. You will definitely need a lawyer, and I cannot recommend one, nor should anyone on this site.

[This page from the NY State bar association](https://www.nysba.org/lawyerreferral/) offers a referral service. [This page from lawhelpny.org](https://www.lawhelpny.org/issues/workers-rights) offers referrals to both free and paid services. [this page from the NY State Attorney General](https://ag.ny.gov/find-attorney) links to various referral sites. So does [this page from LegalMatch](https://www.legalmatch.com/law-library/article/attorney-referral-services-in-new-york.html)

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can sue them if they haven't payed you, however if they haven't payed you they probably have no money.

Comment: Edit: They have money! They have been moving it out of the U.S. Funds outside of the U.S. were frozen and they haven't been able to pay bills, so they're shutting down in the U.S., moving money out, and declaring bankruptcy.